# Switch off output buffering php in lamp

Tags: php, apache, lamp, output-buffering

I want a way to turn off my output buffering. I tried `flush()` and ob functions but didn’t succeeded. In my `etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` value of `output_buffering = 4096`.

When I change it to Off and restart Apache it fails to restart.

```
error in log file is:
[Sat May 31 15:48:26.853420 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1277] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat May 31 17:23:30.461926 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1270] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4 configured -- resuming normal     operations
[Sat May 31 17:23:30.484232 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1270] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: you can change the loglevel which might give you more information. 
e.g. LogLevel debug in httpd.conf. but have you verified it's not running via say ps auxww|grep httpd ?

Comment: the file /etc/phpmyadmin/httpd.conf is empty and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf contains 1 line ServerName localhost.Please tell how to change loglevel?And ps auxwww|grep httpd generated 1 line and i suppose its running.

Answer (score 0):

it's not running. you disregard phpmyadmin. look up /etc/apache2/httpd.conf it's the wrong file or hosed. it might be in /user/local/etc/ you can check your settings with $ httpd -v.

also read this page. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html

notice the **-e option <----**

Comment: the command httpd is not running its showing did you mean http,https,xttpd.... the file's not in /usr/local/etc.